# Is this a good approach for creating pages for multiple content typs with GatsbyJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react.js, gatsby

I'm trying to create pages for multiple content types in Gatsby and I was wondering if this is the right approach:

My gatsby-node.js file:

```js
const path = require(`path`)

const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  // Is this OK?
  if (
    node.internal.type === "Mdx" &&
    node.fileAbsolutePath.includes(`content/posts`)
  ) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: "slug",
      node,
      value: `/blog${value}`,
    })
  }
  if (
    node.internal.type === "Mdx" &&
    node.fileAbsolutePath.includes(`content/projects`)
  ) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: "slug",
      node,
      value: `/project${value}`,
    })
  }
}
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/template-blog-post.js`)
  const projectEntryTemplate = path.resolve(
    `./src/templates/template-project-entry.js`
  )
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      posts: allMdx(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date, fields___slug] }
        limit: 10000
        filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/posts/" } }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
      projects: allMdx(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date, fields___slug] }
        limit: 1000
        filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/projects/" } }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(
      '  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query.'
    )
  }
  const posts = result.data.posts.edges
  const projects = result.data.projects.edges
  posts.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: { id: node.id },
    })
  })

  projects.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: projectEntryTemplate,
      context: { id: node.id },
    })
  })
}
```

My (redacted) gatsby-config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/posts/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: `projects`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/projects/`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Although this works fine and I'm not getting any errors, I'm not sure using two if-statements in gatsby-node.js is the right approach to generating pages for multiple content types. I've searched online and I have not yet found a guide or 'best-practices' when it comes to handling multiple content types with GatsbyJS. Please share if you have!

Could you guys help me out? Am I on the right track or is there improvement to be found?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's definitely a lot of duplicate code in those 2 `if`s. I'd extract it into function and pass different things as parameters.

Then code would look let's say:

```
//not sure about name of function and parameters
function nodeFieldPerType(filePath, getNodePath) {
  if (
    node.internal.type === "Mdx" &&
    node.fileAbsolutePath.includes(filePath)
  ) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: "slug",
      node,
      value: getNodePath(value),
    })
  }
}
```

Then you call it like like:

```
nodeFieldPerType(`content/posts`, value => `/blog${value}`);
nodeFieldPerType(`content/projects`, value => `/project${value}`);
```

This cleans it up a bit. If you keep adding more possible branches, you may need to add more parameters. You can go further to make this as a static configuration and put this into configuration structure, that you fill in advance. Then in your code you just pick the one you need and call it.
Ex:

```
config = {
`content/posts`: { getNodePath:  value => `/blog${value}` }, //object on purpose so that you can add more parameters later
`content/projects`: { getNodePath: value => `/project${value}` },
}
```

And then instead of your `if`s you check if filePath exists in this config and if it does, you call function with parameters in config.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! I reduced the two if-statements with the code you provided and this helped me a lot and gave me more insight into refactoring! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a couple weeks old, and you already have a good solution.  I just wanted to point out a method that is a bit more deterministic/declarative.

You are already using multiple instances of `gatsby-source-filesystem`, and they each have their own `name` property.  That becomes `sourceInstanceName` on the `File` nodes.  You can use that value to simplify your code, while also making it more flexible and efficient.

For example

```js
const path = require(`path`)

const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === "Mdx") {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    const file = getNode(node.parent)
    createNodeField({
      name: "slug",
      node,
      value: `/${file.sourceInstanceName}${value}`,
    })
    createNodeField({
      name: "instance",
      node,
      value: file.sourceInstanceName,
    })
  }
}
```

Now, you can create a more abstract page creation process, which as a bonus is less queries, and less arrays to process:

```js
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date, fields___slug] }
        limit: 10000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
              instance
            }
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
  `)
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(
      '  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query.'
    )
  }

  const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges
  const templates = {}
  posts.forEach(({ node }) => {
    const instance= node.fields.instance
    if (!templates[instance]) {
        templates[instance] = require.resolve(`./src/templates/${instance}`)
    }
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: templates[instance],
      context: {
          id: node.id,
          instance,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

All you have to do is make sure your template names match your `sourceInstanceName` properties, and that your `sourceInstanceName` properties match what you want your routes to be.  You can also use the instance that each node belongs to in your page queries.

Notice that I use `require.resolve()` for the templates, too.  That will resolve it to the correct extension, but it will also fail early if the template doesn't exist.  Might make troubleshooting easier down the road.

---

This is more deterministic because you don't have to do any `fileAbsolutePath` matching, which can be unstable if your route schemes grow.  Instead, you can match the `$instance` GraphQL variable against the `fields.instance` property in your page query filters.

It's more declarative because all I have to do is declare another `gatsby-source-filesystem` instance, then build the template and the content if I want to add a new group.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you so much! I like your approach, and it inspired me to rewrite my createPages using parts of your code. I'm writing an answer with how I approached it and the changes I've made so far. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what the Gatsby docs were missing. Thanks for this pattern, Jeremy. I've linked to it from a related [documentation issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24978) I opened against Gatsby here in mid-2020 after struggling for hours to get a simple set of blog posts added to a site I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for the input! It gave me great insight into solving this problem.

Thanks [@Jeremy Albright](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/220915/jeremy-albright) for your insight and advice. It inspired me to rewrite my node.js file.

My setup so far:

```js
// gatsby-node.js

exports.createPages = require("./gatsby/node/createPages")
exports.onCreateNode = require("./gatsby/node/onCreateNode")
```

I'm still learning react I find it helpful to split up the code into groups, to get a better understanding of the process and how they function; I split up my gatsby-node.js file into a dedicated folder.

```js
// creatPages.js

const path = require(`path`)
const query = require("../data/data-query")

module.exports = async ({ graphql, reporter, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const templatesDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../src/templates/")

  const templates = {
    blog: path.resolve(templatesDirectory, "template-blog-post.js"),
    projects: path.resolve(templatesDirectory, "template-project-entry.js"),
  }

  const result = await graphql(query.local.content)

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(
      '  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query.'
    )
  }

  const mdxContent = result.data.allMdx.edges

  mdxContent.forEach(({ node }) => {
    const instance = node.fields.instance
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: templates[instance],
      context: {
        id: node.id,
        instance,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

I like the approach of letting gatsby-source-filesystem define the templates and content types. What I don't like is the strict naming. I would need to name the template files to something that also works well within the URL structure. Here is where I hit a snag.

I want the name of the file to say something about it. Naming a blog template file just "blog" seems a bit vague. The approach I came up with requires a little more work, but it gave me the chance to name my templates how I want to and use my 'weird' naming scheme.

I used `templatesDirectory` to get the template path and `templates` to get the instance and combine the actual template name to the instance name

```js
// onCreateNode.js

const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")
module.exports = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === "Mdx") {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    const file = getNode(node.parent)
    createNodeField({
      name: "slug",
      node,
      value: `/${file.sourceInstanceName}${value}`,
    })
    createNodeField({
      name: "instance",
      node,
      value: file.sourceInstanceName,
    })
  }
}
```

My onCreateNode.js file is copy-paste from Jeremy.

---

What is your opinion on this approach? I'm struggling with finding 'best practices' and documentation for working with multiple content types. So many people approach this entirely differently.

I would like to know what you guys think about this!

Cheers!